# UITableView Background Scroll but NOT Repeat

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to set a `UITableView` background using the following method:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]]];
```

This works great for making the background scroll with the table. However, my background image fades into a solid color, so *instead* of the background repeating, I'd love for it to just scroll up and just fit to the screen height. Then I can set `self.view`'s `backgroundColor` to be the solid color and it will look great.

Other options seem to be blitting a small image at the bottom, but this seems complicated and I didn't quite understand how to draw the background and blit using `CGContext`.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

[image: Example Of What I Want]

Comment: can you post the screen shot of what it is now, and what you want it to be?

Comment: @Viral - I added an image of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will work but you should try creating a resizeable UIImage for the background:

If you want the last line of pixels to repeat you would call the

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
```

on your image ( `[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]` )
with edgeinsets: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(backgroundImage.size.height-1,0,0,0)`
and resizingMode: `UIImageResizingModeStretch`

the complete call would look like

```
UIImage* backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"];
UIImage* newBackgroundImage = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(backgroundImage.size.height-1,0,0,0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

And now you could try to use this image for the pattern creation:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newBackgroundImage]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything differently. I think the problem with this solution is the tableView doesn't increase its frame.size.height when it scrolls and thus it just repeats the image, vs stretching the background color.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
UIImageView* bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"];
bgImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
[self.tableView addSubview:bgImageView];
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:bgImageView];
```

In my case it worked fine. I didn't test it with a lot of cells which are reused. But it should work :D